# FEM solution for onedimensional boundary value problem doesn't evaluate

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

**modified**

Based on this, unfortunately closed, question [How can we know on how many parts is domain splitted with MaxCellMeasure? [closed]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290456/how-can-we-know-on-how-many-parts-is-domain-splitted-with-maxcellmeasure) I would like to know why `NDSolve` doesn't evaluate:

```
ode = y''[t] + y'[t] + 3*y[t] - Sin[t];
sol = NDSolve[{ode == NeumannValue[0, t == 10],
DirichletCondition[y[t] == 0, t == 0]}, y, {t, 0, 10},
Method -> {"FiniteElement" , "MeshOptions" -> "MaxCellMeasure->0.1"}]
```

Usually FiniteElement works for boundary problems without problems.

Without the option `"MeshOptions" -> "MaxCellMeasure->0.1"` it evaluates as expected.

What could be the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: MMA version 13.3. I get a solution.

Comment: **I would like to know why NDSolve doesn't evaluate** it works for me on V 13.3.1

Comment: @Nasser  Thanks for your reply. See my modified question.

Comment: @DanielHuber  Thanks for your reply. See my modified question.

Comment: Yes, Your modified version does not evaluate now.  The `MeshOptions` option made it not evaluate.  But you wrote it wrong. This makes it work `Method->{"FiniteElement","MeshOptions"->{MaxCellMeasure->0.1}}`

Comment: @Nasser Such easy ? Thank you very much!

Comment: I just used the syntax as shown on   https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html  and searched the page for `MeshOptions` to find it. may be this value was not supported in 12.2. I do not know.

Comment: @Nasser Thanks! It's my simple mistake setting the `"` .  `NDSolveValue[{ode == NeumannValue[0, t == 10], 
  DirichletCondition[y[t] == 0, t == 0]}, y, {t, 0, 10}, 
 Method -> {"FiniteElement" , 
   "MeshOptions" -> "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1  }]` works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a typo: You used

```
"MaxCellMeasure->0.1"
```

but you should use:

```
"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1
```

Comment: **but you should use:** but this also works `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1` ?  i.e. `MaxCellMeasure` does not have to be string. Using V 13.3.1

Comment: @Nasser Yes, why should that not work?

Comment: @user21 Thanks, it was a simple mistake...

Comment: **why should that not work?** But that is what I was asking :)  so both versions work. String and no string.

Comment: @Nasser, yes, correct both should work. Is there is a system symbol then the symbol and a string version work, else only a string version works.